# Using cache tags for a particular node list

Tags: 8, caching

Caching in Drupal 8 is great, but documentation is thin (at this time) on using cache tags for render arrays in Drupal 8.

I have some code that basically generates a list of node teasers, say for content types "books" and "magazines". I'm caching the list to speed things up. I would like to refresh the list every time a "book" or "magazine" is added/deleted/edited. So I have a render array that looks like this:

```
$build = array(
  '#type' => 'markup',
  '#markup' => $sMarkup,        
  '#cache' => [
    'keys' => ['home-all','home'],
    'tags'=> ['node_list'], // invalidate cache when any node content is added/changed etc.
    'max-age' => '36600', // invalidate cache after 10h
  ],
);
```

By using the cache tag ['node_list'], the cache invalidates properly when content is added or edited, but will also invalidate when a content type not being listed here is changed, say "casette".

What cache tags can I use to limit the invalidation to when only "book" or "magazine" is added/changed/deleted? I've tried using: ['book_list','magazine_list']
but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting Drupal 8.9.0, there is a new `ENTITY_TYPE_list:BUNDLE` cache tag added (see the [change record](https://www.drupal.org/node/3107058)).

So in your case you would simply need to tag our list with `node_list:book`.

https://www.drupal.org/node/3107058

Answer (score 4):

In this case I know two options.

One - Include all node tags (node:{#id}), if doesn't matter if a new node of a particular type was added.

Two - Create and control your own cache tag, and invalidade it when you want.

I'm developing a site that was needed create a term list cache per vocab_id. In this case every time that a term from a particular vocab_id change/add/delete the cache tag is invalided using `Cache::invalidateTags($tag_id)` then my block will be rebuild.

**Edit 1**

Example:

```
use Drupal\Core\Cache\Cache;

function filters_invalidate_vocabulary_cache_tag($vocab_id) {
  Cache::invalidateTags(array('filters_vocabulary:' . $vocab_id));
}
```

In your case maybe is just change `$vocab_id` for `$node_type`.

Comment: Thanks @vagner - I've started going down option 2, because I need to refresh when a new node is added. Having troubles invalidating the tags though, trying like this: \Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheTagsInvalidator::invalidateTags(["myTag"]); - which gives an error

Comment: @ryrye added an example.

Comment: CacheTagsInvalidator is a service that Cache:: wraps. You can also use that, especially in a controller/service, but then you have to call it on the cache tags invalidator service. Also, see https://www.drupal.org/project/views_custom_cache_tag if you want to use this approach with views.

Answer (score 1):

See the contrib module [handy_cache_tags](https://www.drupal.org/project/handy_cache_tags). I haven't used it (yet), but it purports to do exactly what you are looking for. From the module's description:

> The module provides the following cache tags for you to use:

```
handy_cache_tags:[entity_type]
handy_cache_tags:[entity_type]:[entity_bundle]
```